# UnicodeDecodeError with Hex Value

Tags: python

When I run

`u''.startswith('x\x9c')`

I end up with an exception

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Why does `'x\x9c'` get decoded as an ascii character as opposed to a unicode character as I have run it on the unicode string `u''`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because python can't decode `'x\x9c'` as its non-ascii character.
Try this:

```
import unidecode
u''.startswith(unidecode.unidecode_expect_nonascii('x\x9c'))
```

Output: returns False
As now unicode string `'x\x9c'` is now represented in ASCII format by unidecode libraray function.

Also, this is happening because you tried to mix unicode and byte string. i.e if you need to check `a.startswith(b)` than both should be unicode or byte str.
If this is not followed, you get Unicode decode error.

Hope this helps !

Comment: But why is it trying to convert `x\x9c` to `ascii` as opposed to `unicode`?